# How is a package entry automatically inserted in package.json file on installing?

Tags: node.js, npm

I was experimenting on node.js and npm libraries, and I wanted to know how is the package.json file updated on installing a file using npm.

Like what's the steps followed, how to update the particular field like dependencies which already has a JSON as a value.

For example,

there exists a number of fields inside package.json with one of it being dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
  "vue": "^2.5.2"
}
```

Now if I add a package called XYZ in it the list is updated as follow:

```
"dependencies": {
  "vue": "^2.5.2",
  "XYZ": "^0.0.1"
}
```

I am trying to understand the logic/code written to update the dependencies list.
How does the node read the package file, get the dependencies field as a variable, update it and insert it back into the file?

Any lead will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean *"how"*? NPM does it for you.

Comment: Exactly. I am interested in finding out "how" does NPM do it.

Comment: Read file, parse file, update content, stringify content, write file? NPM is open source, if you want more detail I'd suggest looking at the code: https://github.com/npm/cli